# How to prevent a button from moving when resizing the window

Tags: html, css

I can use some help as I am new to html coding. anyway,
I've made a carousel with bootstrap. The carousel itself works fine. But after placing a button in the carousel, (using top: (px) and right: (px) as I don't know how to place it where I want otherwise)it still works fine. Until I start resizing the window. The background becomes smaller, but the button kind of stays the same size. So it starts moving around and what once were 2 buttons next to eachother, are now 2 buttons with alot of space between them. Here, have a look at my code:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <title>Galaxy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <style type="text/css">
</style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="galaxy3.jpg"> 
                        <div class="slide1"></div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div class="bannertext">
                                <h1>Santorodesign</h1>
                                <p>A website made by Michael</p>
                                <div class="mobileHide"> <button id="headerbutton-nederlands">Nederlands</button></div>
                                <div class="mobileHide"> <button id="headerbutton-english">English</button></div>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="slide2"></div>
                    <img src="galaxy2.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="bannertext2">
                            <h1>Explore the galaxy<h1>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
                </a>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="firstrow">
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img id="mercury" src="mercury.png"> <br>
                (text) <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Mercury</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img id="earth" src="earth.png"> <br>
                (text)<br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about the Earth</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img id="venus" src="venus.png"> <br>
                (text) <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Venus</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}
#firstrow {
   font-size: 2em;
   padding: 100px 0 0 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 550px;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
   background: #DCDCDC;
   position: relative;
}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands { display: none; }
    #headerbutton-english { display: none; }
}
.planet {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
    .planet img {
        height: 300px;
        max-width: none;
    }

    .bannertext {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        line-height: 15px;
    }
    .bannertext h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .bannertext2 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
 .mobileShow { display: none;}
 .mobileHide { display: inline;}
     /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen
        and (max-device-width : 480px){
        .mobileShow { display: inline;}
        .mobileHide { display: none;}
        .planet img{
            height: 200px;
        }
        }
#headerbutton-nederlands {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: -90px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #778899;
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;  
    border: white 2px solid ;    
}
#headerbutton-english {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #778899;
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;  
    border: white 2px solid ;
}
```

basically what I want is that the buttons + the text inside of the buttons also resize when the window becomes smaller. As if the buttons are a part of the image.

Thank you for your time. 
-Michael

Comment: judging by the 2 very different answers, it might be a good idea to clarify your question with a http://codepen.io or http://jsfiddle.net demo

Comment: possible duplicate with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css). If you plan in the future to write SCSS instead of pure CSS you can check also [this mixin](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the buttons to scale relative to the size of the screen, you need to style them with relative units instead of pixels.  You can use, `%` to size them relative to their parent element, `em` or `rem` to size them relative to the size of the font, or --most likely for your needs-- `vh` or `vw` to scale them relative to the height and width of the viewport, respectively.

Assuming your initial styles work on a viewport 1140px wide (just an arbitrary starting point), the following CSS may get you headed in the right direction:

```
#headerbutton-nederlands {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    bottom: 3vw;
    right: -8vw;
    -webkit-border-radius: .5vw;
    line-height: 4.3vw;
    color: white;
    background-color: #778899;
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;  
    border: white 2px solid ;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position: relative;` property to the `.bannertext` element. What this does is **when a child element is absolutely positioned inside a relatively positioned parent, it makes sure the child element stays relative from the bounds of the parent**. So change `.bannertext` in your CSS to the following and it should work.

```
.bannertext {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

You may need to update the `top` and `right` properties though so it's back in the right place you wanted again.